# How can I cache docfx installation in my GitHub action?

Tags: github-actions, npm-install, docfx

I am writing a github action for which I need to install docfx. This step takes about 12 seconds: I know that [npm install can be made super fast through caching](https://www.voorhoede.nl/en/blog/super-fast-npm-install-on-github-actions/), however npm has a package-lock you can use, but my docfx step is completely automatic so I don't want any `docfx.json` files floating around.

Is there any way I can still cache it or do I need to store some kind of metadata file? I know, it's kindof a silly question but I'm not well-versed in github actions.

Comment: Yes, you can still cache it on its own without using any files. You can use your own hardcoded keys and that should work fine.

Comment: See https://github.com/actions/cache/#creating-a-cache-key.